# Mystery with ValueQ

Tags: core-language, expression-test

Consider the following

```
ClearAll[jd];
ValueQ[jd]
```

We expect `False` and get it. Now consider

```
ClearAll[jd];
ValueQ[jd /. {foo -> Unique[]}]
```

which yields `True`. But

```
jd /. {foo -> Unique[]}
```

is just `jd` and has no value defined. What's going on here?

Comment: `ValueQ[]` is a funny beast. Try `{ValueQ@E, ValueQ@Sin@E, ValueQ@Pi, ValueQ@Sin@Pi, ValueQ@N@Pi}` :)

Comment: good grief! that's a thicket :)

Comment: [some related questions on ValueQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+title%3Avalueq)

Comment: According to the [doc](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ValueQ.html), "ValueQ gives False only if expr would not change if it were to be entered as Mathematica input.", so the *Value* in `ValueQ` does not mean numerical value I think.

Comment: See the definition for yourself: `ClearAttributes[ValueQ, Protected];
ClearAttributes[ValueQ, ReadProtected];
ValueQ // Information;
DownValues[ValueQ][[1]] /. {System`Dump`s -> s, System`Dump`h -> h}`

Comment: So in your case we have (both give `True`): `! Hold[Evaluate[jd /. {foo -> Unique[]}]] === 
  Hold[jd /. {foo -> Unique[]}]`, as
`! Hold[Evaluate[jd]] === Hold[jd /. {foo -> Unique[]}]`

Answer (score 4):

If, say, `f` has the `HoldAll` attribute, you should not assume `f[2]` to be the same as `f[1+1]`. `ValueQ` has such attribute.

`ValueQ` tests whether the expression changes upon evaluation.

`jd /. {foo -> Unique[]}` evaluates to `jd` which is different from the original unevaluated form `jd /. {foo -> Unique[]}`. Therefore, `ValueQ[jd /. {foo -> Unique[]}]` gives `True`