# How to ValueQ a symbol, constructing the symbol name from strings?

Tags: core-language

In a function I'm writing, I need to check whether a particular symbol has been assigned a value (any value) in a particular context. This would work:

```
ValueQ[box`a]
```

However, the problem is that the name of the symbol to be checked must be passed to the function as a variable. I've tried passing a string argument `name` and then doing this:

```
ValueQ[ToExpression["box`"<>name]]
```

but that always returns `True`, presumably because all `ValueQ` really does is check whether the expression it's given would change if typed into *Mathematica*, and this one clearly would as the string concatenation and then `ToExpression` conversion occur. (see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39407/mystery-with-valueq) and similar.)

I can't for the life of me figure out how to programmatically specify the argument to `ValueQ` in a way that doesn't always produce `True`. I've tried wrapping the `ToExpression` with `Evaluate`, `Unevaluated`, or `Symbol`, with no luck. There's always *some* transformation that happens.

I've also tried checking whether `DownValues` is empty (which would be good enough for my purposes), like this:

```
DownValues[ToExpression["box`"<>name]]
```

and I run into a similar problem: `DownValues` complains that "Argument ToExpression[box`<>name] at position 1 is expected to be a symbol". I can't figure out how to construct a legitimate symbol from the strings. These produce the same kind of error:

```
DownValues[ToExpression["box`" <> name, InputForm, Hold]]
DownValues[Symbol["box`" <> name]]
```

Any suggestions? Thanks...

Comment: You need to use ``ToExpression["box`" <> name, InputForm, ValueQ]``.  This question is essentially a duplicate of [How can I test properties of a symbol from the string name without the symbol completely evaluating](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/197/142).  Voting to close.